# lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu "crashes" after installing KDE4.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lightdm, login-screen

I have a weird problem, which I didn't found anything on the internet about.

I installed KDE4.10 (from kubuntu-ppa/backports) a week ago, and it changed the loginscreen. After there was something weird with my sound (doesn't matter anymore) I uninstalled kubuntu-desktop, rebooted and then i just got  `mountall: connection to plymouth disconnected`. After installing kubuntu-desktop again. The problem was gone, but I had again this KDE-like loginscreen.

Later I figured out, that i can change the greeter in

> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

from `greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter` to  `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu` but this brings back the old problem which can be seen in the picture i linked above.

Does anyone know how i can fix this? I would like to have the standard-loginscreen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the greeter session that worked in my case is:

> greeter-session=unity-greeter

Maybe you want to try that.

Answer (score -1):

maybe u must reinstall kdm or lightdm so the configuration comeback to default again . And i hope this help u.

Open terminal : sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm ,

select u want bro, lightdm, kdm or gdm

[image]

[image]

If you want using boot screen ubuntu just remve package plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo and plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text then reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text.

Comment: This does not work since kubuntu now uses lightdm too.

Comment: Also, changing boot-screen is easier with `update-alternatives --configure default.plymouth`